# Height of UIControl does not change programmatically within UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, uiscrollview, ios8.1

I have **scrollView** and Button inside it with 20 height  when I change the the height of button programmatically in **viewDidLoad()**

```
button.frame.size.height = 30
```

the height is changed successfully but when **scrollViewDidScroll** called the button return to its initial height -> 20

Note : when I change the height of button I change  `scrollView.contentSize.height += 10`                                  (20 -> 30)

xcode 6.1 and iOS 8.1

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: yes I use , but I can not dispense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using Auto-layout, why not add a constraint on the button's height?

If you need to change the height at runtime, you would then have to change the constraint constant(you can access constraints defined in IB like any other IBOutlet), not the frame.

**Edit:** I assume you are using Interface Builder, then you can add a constraint on the button's height explicitly in code using this:

```
[self addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:yourButton
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                               relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                  toItem:nil
                                               attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                              multiplier:1.0
                                                constant:30.0]];
```

Comment: please @joakim is there any simple example ?

Comment: @Hazem how are you currently setting the height? Are you using height constrain or not ?

Comment: @zellb I don't have height constrain on button